# Why is my computer automatically starting up after I've shut it down?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have Windows 8 installed on my testing machine. Since I installed it, when I shut down the computer, after a while (1-3mins) it starts up on its own.
The computer never showed that kind of behavior before.
Any ideas what might be the problem? (No, there are no wake on lan messages send in my network.)

UPDATE:
It is not wake on HID.

Disabling Fast Startup had no effect on the issue.

Comment: I shut it down from the active corner menu, using 'shut down'.

Comment: Your power button is stuck and after a few seconds it turns on again. Lol

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by a new feature of Windows 8 called `Fast Startup` which puts the computer in a special state called [hibernation shutdown](https://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/10/25/windows-8-windows-server-2012-faster-boot-process.aspx?Redirected=true). It seems that some hardware configurations do not like this.

How to disable Fast Start:

1. Open start screen, and move your mouse to the right pane.
2. Enter "Power Options" in the Search field.
3. Click Settings and select Change what the power buttons do from the
   left pane that appears.
4. In System Settings, scroll down to the Shutdown settings section and
   uncheck Turn on fast startup(recommend).

Ref:
[Delivering fast boot times in Windows 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8);
[What Is Fast Startup In Windows 8 & How To Disable It](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/what-is-fast-startup-windows-8-disable-it/)

Comment: It did not help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your computer woke up by pressing keyboard or mouse.

Try this:

- Control Panel > Mouse > Hardware > Properties > Change Settings >
  Power Management and uncheck "Allow this device to wake the
  computer".
- Control Panel > Keyboard > Hardware > Properties > Change
  Settings > Power Management and uncheck "Allow this device to wake
  the computer".

Comment: As stated in my question "It is not wake on HID.". I have tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Win8.  Found out it was Media Center turning it on to do an update.  This URL explains how to shut it off.

http://answerquestions.hubpages.com/hub/Why-Does-My-Computer-Turn-On-By-Itself

Bob's suggestion is also excellent...type "powercfg -lastwake" at the command prompt to find out what most recently started your machine.

Jim.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable automatic maintenance.

1. Go to "Control Panel" > "System and Security" > "Security and Maintenance".
2. Click the down arrow to the right of "Maintenance".
3. Click on "Change maintenance settings".
4. Uncheck "Allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the scheduled time".