# Windows 8 Boot Reason

Tags: windows-8.1, event-log

My friend asked me to troubleshoot an issue where his Windows 8.1 desktop would boot up automatically roughly 24 hours after previous shutdown. I'm really sceptical about it but the Event Viewer log seems to backup his story.

Is there a way in the Event Viewer logs to see what caused a particular boot event, like the power button is clicked, a network boot request arrived, or a scheduled boot has fired, etc?

Comment: maybe the maintenance task at 3AM wakes up the device?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/493207/why-is-my-computer-automatically-starting-up-after-ive-shut-it-down. Check the command specified. Is this PC set to wake on LAN?